# Is this WPF ViewModel-first hookup pattern using implicit DataTemplates possible in WinUI 3?

Tags: winui-3

I have watched Brian Noyes excellent course *WPF MVVM in Depth* on Pluralsight. I'm attempting to recreate a structure from there in WinUI 3 but cannot get it to work.

The idea is to create a navigation between different views that are displayed in a `ContentControl` within the main window. `MainWindowViewModel` exposes a property called `CurrentViewModel`. Through commands on buttons this property gets set to different values and are updated with the normal flow using `INotifyPropertyChange`. This property is bound to from the `Content`-property of a `ContentControl` in the layout of `MainWindow`. In the resources of this window a few `DataTemplate`s are defined and by *matching the type* of the bound object the proper view is inserted in to the content control. Here are the relevant parts of `MainWindow.xaml` (note that all this is done in WPF):

```xml
<Window <!--Snipped-->>
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type cust:CustomerListViewModel}">
            <cust:CustomerListView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type order:OrderViewModel}">
            <order:OrderView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <!--Snipped-->
        <Grid>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Can this be done in WinUI 3?

- I've moved the resource dictionary to the root Grid-element
- I've tried using both `{Binding}` and `{x:Bind ViewModel.CurrentViewModel}`
- The markup extension of type `"{x:Type cust:CustomerListViewModel}"` seems to not be available in WinUI 3, I've instead tried `x:DataType=cust:CustomerListViewModel`

The closest I've come is that the `ToString()` of the view models are rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should consider using the [Template Studio for WinUI](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TemplateStudio.TemplateStudioForWinUICs). You can implement navigation with few clicks.

I'm not familiar with the course you mentioned, but I guess is something close to what you are trying to do.

BTW, I'm using the [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/mvvm/introduction) NuGet package to implement MVVM design, which I strongly recommend you to check it out.

This is a simple example using buttons to navigate.

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;

namespace NavigationDataTemplateSelector;

public partial class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    // A "CurrentViewModel" UI-interactive property will be auto-generated.
    private object? currentViewModel;

    [RelayCommand]
    // A "GoToCommand" command will be auto-generated.
    private void GoTo(string viewModelName)
    {
        CurrentViewModel = viewModelName switch
        {
            nameof(CustomerListViewModel) => new CustomerListViewModel(),
            nameof(OrderViewModel) => new OrderViewModel(),
            _ => null,
        };
    }
}
```

**CustomerListViewModel.cs**

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace NavigationDataTemplateSelector;

public partial class CustomerListViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    public ObservableCollection<string> customers = new()
    {
        "A",
        "B",
        "C",
    };
}
```

**OrderViewModel.cs**

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using System;

namespace NavigationDataTemplateSelector;

public partial class OrderViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    public Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;

namespace NavigationDataTemplateSelector;

public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel ViewModel { get; } = new();
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

As you can see here, I'm using a `TemplateSelector` to select which `DataTemplate` to use as a `Content`.

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="NavigationDataTemplateSelector.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:NavigationDataTemplateSelector"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate
                x:Key="CustomerListViewModel"
                x:DataType="local:CustomerListViewModel">
                <Grid>
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Customers, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate
                x:Key="OrderViewModel"
                x:DataType="local:OrderViewModel">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Id, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
            <local:ViewTemplateSelector
                x:Key="ViewTemplateSelector"
                CustomerListViewTemplate="{StaticResource CustomerListViewModel}"
                OrderViewTemplate="{StaticResource OrderViewModel}" />
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,*">
            <Button
                x:Name="CustomerListViewButton"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.GoToCommand}"
                CommandParameter="CustomerListViewModel"
                Content="Go to customer list view" />
            <Button
                x:Name="OrderViewButton"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.GoToCommand}"
                CommandParameter="OrderViewModel"
                Content="Go to order view" />
            <ContentControl
                Grid.Row="2"
                Content="{x:Bind ViewModel.CurrentViewModel, Mode=OneWay}"
                ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ViewTemplateSelector}" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

**ViewTemplateSelector.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System;

namespace NavigationDataTemplateSelector;

public class ViewTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate? CustomerListViewTemplate { get; set; }

    public DataTemplate? OrderViewTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate? SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        return item switch
        {
            CustomerListViewModel => CustomerListViewTemplate,
            OrderViewModel => OrderViewTemplate,
            _ => null,
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer! I will definitely check out the MVVM toolkit and the template studio extension.

I implemented your solution and got it to work, but not when I extracted the grid in the data template with key `CustomerListViewModel` into its own `UserControl` (`CustomerListView`). I understand that to use `x:Bind` I need to use some explicit property on the list, e.g. by setting the view model instance to a prop called `ViewModel`. Is this possible?

It did work with `{Binding}` however, but my understanding `x:Bind` comes with greater type safety and performance.